# Does a downvote to a view on meta mean disagreement?

Tags: discussion, meta, voting

If so, when all votes are down we can know what they are against

Comment: Usually, you can leave a comment asking the downvoters what they disagree with.

Comment: To @user202729's point, downvoters should be leaving a comment if they disagree with something... especially on meta.

Comment: @Poke Unless (the downvoter think that) it's obvious, or leaving a comment does not help (with improving the post (especially for feature-request)).

Comment: @user202729 They should still be leaving a comment in those cases unless other comments encompass the same rationale in which case that seems like good grounds for upvoting a comment. If you just don't like a feature request then you can provide constructive feedback on why you think it's a bad idea or how it can be improved.

Comment: What is a "*downvote to a view*"?

Comment: @PeterTaylor An answer to "Is xxx allowed?", etc

Answer (score 1):

## On [feature-request](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) answers, yes

Quoting the [Help Center](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta):

> Voting is different on meta. Like normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta
> allows members to vote on questions and answers. For most posts, votes
> reflect the perceived usefulness: well-written, well-reasoned,
> well-researched posts tend to get more attention and more upvotes.
> Highly-voted and frequently-linked posts may become part of the
> community-curated FAQ or codified as part of the site’s Help pages.
>
> Unlike normal Stack Exchange sites, Meta invites the community to
> discuss, debate and propose changes to the way the community itself
> behaves, as well as how the software itself works. On posts tagged
> feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement with the
> proposed change rather than just the quality or usefulness of the post
> itself.

Also, this type of disagreement-downvoting leaks out to the rest of meta as well.  Questions or non-[feature-request](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request) commonly gets voted down due to disagreement, though these votes aren't binding.